# downloading attachments in SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, attachments

I can't download any attachments from the *list* or *library* in **SharePoint 2013**.

Even I can't see the attachments. I only see the paperclips. What should I do?

Comment: Even can't you download attachments in list item edit mode?

Comment: yes I'm not able to see any attachment except the paperclips

Comment: Can you download the attachment which is uploaded by you?
Did you check your permission on the list?

Comment: yes, I have full control . I uploaded by myself. but can't  download or read the attachments

Comment: did you double check the downloads folder of your browser that the attachment was not downloaded there?

Comment: yes I checked  the downloads folder. there was nothing.

Comment: Is there anybody to help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you see the attachment name on the view form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Receiver and create another list (ListA) to record your attachment link.

Maybe your process is:

1. Users add list items and attachments
2. List event will be fired
3. Use Event Receiver to get attachment url and then Write into ListA

You also can refer to the following web site:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b693eb84-b846-4f0f-93c1-276cf931c746/how-to-get-attachment-in-itemadded-event-receiver

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077770/how-to-retrieve-list-item-attachments-with-sharepoint-2013-event-receiver-in-cor

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSlink to make attachment download by clicking on Paper Clip Icon representing attachment.
You can use the code and explaination provided in the below link.

[Make List Item Attachment link clickable with JSLink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117193/make-list-item-attachment-link-clickable-with-jslink)

It works wonder.